# does microsoft android face api support detections on real time camera stream?

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

Can we use the newly launched Microsoft cognitive services for crowd analysis and audience measurement? I need to create an application which can detect faces in live video and provide the characteristics like gender, age and mood

Answer (score 1):

Face API is designed for image processing, if you want to use it on camera stream, you need to handle the input yourself. Something like just picking several frames and send the image to Face API cloud service. If possible, you can have this [1] as reference (though the code might be a little bit old).

[1] https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis